# Deploying java code on Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, websphere-8

I have an updated EAR FILE which contains few java code changes and is currently deployed on WAS 6.1. Now we are in process of upgrading the websphere to 8.5. Will the same EAR file work on WAS 8.5? Will just compiling the code be sufficient to run on WAS 8.5. Do we have to do any changes to make it work on 8.5 version. And what version of jre and jdk does 8.5 supports.Please help

Comment: It depends on what is inside your EAR/WAR. In general the shift from 6.1 to 8.5 should not be a problem. And you don't need to recompile. Java support should be at least 7, I think 8 is possible.

Comment: actually was 6.1 supports jdk 1.4. Will it support the same 1.4 version of java

Answer (score 1):

WAS 8.5 supports Java 6 and 7.

See this page, go to the **Supported Software** tab and scroll down to **Java SDK**. http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProductByComponent?deliverableId=1337870535828&duComponent=Server_11854150A6C511E2A4CA497F0925FE1B

As Marged said in a comment, whether you'll need to make changes to your EAR depends on what is in it. The Knowledge Center has this page on migrating from previous versions to 8.5: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/welc6topmigrating.html?lang=en

Comment: the EAR file now contains just a small code change of few lines. thing is the EAR file earlier had jdk version of 1.4 .. will that work on was 8.5.5

Comment: Normally this works and Java 1.4 should run on Java 7 just fine because Java is backwards compatible:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html